# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module node_modu les\@angular\core\fesm2015\testing.mjs not supported. Angular 13, Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular13

After an upgrade to Angular 13, my Jest unit tests are failing and i cannot understand why and how to fix them. I´ve searched for a while now and i have found some info for similar cases. It seems the reason for such fails is a change in Angular 13 which makes Jest somewhat incompatible, even though I´m using the latest version of Jest (27.5).

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "app-angular",
  "version": "6.67.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "serve-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "serve-open-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --open",
    "dev-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c dev",
    "dev-test-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c dev-test",
    "staging-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c staging",
    "release-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c release",
    "prod-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c production",
    "test-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test App-Angular",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.ts",
    "test:coverage": "yarn jest --coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint App-Angular",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "release": "standard-version",
    "commit": "git-cz"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.3",
    "@digitalascetic/ngx-pica": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/data": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngx-progressbar/core": "5.3.2",
    "@ngx-progressbar/http-client": "3.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^7.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^6.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^6.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^4.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^6.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^8.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^6.4.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler": "^3.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.5",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.2",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-recurrence": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-material": "^5.1.1",
    "angular-fittext": "^2.1.1",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "changedpi": "^1.0.4",
    "exifr": "^7.1.3",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.18",
    "jest-mock": "^27.5.1",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^5.0.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^12.5.0",
    "pica": "^9.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "secure-ls": "^1.2.6",
    "subsink": "^1.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript-string-operations": "^1.4.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "13.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.2.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.2.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^11.1.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "standard-version": "^9.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~10.6.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

And my jest.config.ts file:

```
    import type { Config } from '@jest/types';
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testRunner: "jest-jasmine2",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/dist/",
    "<rootDir>/src/test.ts"
  ],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      stringifyContentPathRegex: "\\.html$",
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          "jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer",
          "jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  roots: [
    "<rootDir>",
    "./src",
    "./projects"
  ],
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>",
    "./src",
    "./projects"
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

export default config;
```

The error i receive when i run **yarn test** is:

```
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.5
$ jest --config ./jest.config.ts
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\jes
t.config.ts
  Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modu
les\@angular\core\fesm2015\testing.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modules\@angular\core\fe
sm2015\testing.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modules\jest-confi
g\build\readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:136:13)
    at async readConfig (C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modules\jest-config\build\ind
ex.js:225:18)
    at async readConfigs (C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modules\jest-config\build\in
dex.js:420:26)
    at async runCLI (C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modules\@jest\core\build\cli\inde
x.js:132:59)
    at async Object.run (C:\Projects\appAngularfrontend\kendoUpdate\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\in
dex.js:155:37)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Running into the same issue after Angular 12 upgrade. Any luck finding the fix?